# Left Shift Operator Spectrum Q2

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Consider $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$. Let $R: \ell^2(\mathbb{Z}) \to \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ be such that $R((a_n)) = (a_{n+1})$.

I need to prove that, given $z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z| >1$, the two series

$$(I-zR)^{-1} = z^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{R}{z} \right)^k$$  and for $|z| <1$
$$(I-zR)^{-1} = -R^{-1} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{z}{R} \right)^k$$ converge  as an operator in $B(\ell^2(\mathbb{Z}))$, the space of bounded operators on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ with the standard operator norm. Is it best to prove that the partial sums are cauchy in $B(\ell^2(\mathbb{Z}))$?

Also, I'm a bit confused as to what $\left( \frac{R}{z} \right)^k$ means as an operator. How does it act on an element in this space?

Comment: Isn't $\left( \frac{R}{z} \right)^k$ the operator $\underbrace{R \circ R \circ \cdots \circ R}_{k \text{ times} }\circ\frac{1}{z^k}$. i.e $\left(\left( \frac{R}{z} \right)^k(a)\right)_n = \frac{a_{n+k}}{z^k}$

Comment: @Tryss This is what I assumed, but no one has ever confirmed this with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does $\frac{R}{z}$ mean? It means that someone is a fan of sloppy notation. It means $\frac{1}{z}R$, which makes sense because $\frac{1}{z}$ is a scalar and $R$ is a vector in the vector space of linear operators. Similarly $\frac{z}{R}$ no doubt stands for $z R^{-1}$, which makes sense in Mathematics.

The operator $R$ and its inverse are isometric, meaning that $\|Rx\|=\|x\|$ and $\|R^{-1}x\|=\|x\|$ for all vectors $x\in \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$. So $\|R^{n}\|=1$ and $\|(R^{-1})^{n}\|=1$ for all $n=0,1,2,3,\cdots$, which is enough to give the convergence of your series in the operator norm.

Comment: wonderful. This is how I ended up arguing after understanding that R was norm preserving and how to interpretation that slight abuse of notation. +1,accepted

Comment: Indeed I did. Thank you for your help

Comment: @AnthonyPeter : You're welcome.